# Android HttpPost Send ArrayList

Tags: android, http-post

I try to send  `arraylists` with `httpPost`. I searched and learn how to can send `httpPost`. I wrote  code with can  send simple `httpPost`, but I do not know  how I can send `Arraylist`.

This is my code:

```
public static String SendHttpPost(String Url,String method,HashMap<String,String> args,int id)
{
      HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url);

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", method));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("args", args.put("objectType", String.valueOf(0))));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("args", args.put("languageISOCode", "eng")));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", String.valueOf(id)));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        response= httpclient.execute(httppost);


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch blockF
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    return String.valueOf(response);
}
```

I would to send like this `Arralist`:

```
{"objectType" : 0,"languageISOCode" : "eng"}
```

If anyone knows solution, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to send **named arguments** and not just an array list (mapping of numbers to strings), I would suggest this method I'm using:

```
private static void setHttpParameters(HttpUriRequest request,
        String... alternatingNameValueParams) throws IOException {
    if (request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        for (int i = 0; i < alternatingNameValueParams.length; i += 2) {
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                    alternatingNameValueParams[i],
                    alternatingNameValueParams[i + 1]));
        }
        ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request)
                .setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    } else {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        for (int i = 0; i < alternatingNameValueParams.length; i += 2) {
            params.setParameter(alternatingNameValueParams[i],
                    alternatingNameValueParams[i + 1]);
        }
        request.setParams(params);
    }
}
```

Now replace everything inside your SendHttpPost method with the following:

```
HttpResponse response = null;
BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
ClientConnectionManager mgr = httpclient.getConnectionManager();
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
    params, mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url);

try {
    // Add your data
    setHttpParameters(httppost, "method", method, "objectType",
        String.valueOf(0), "languageISOCode", "eng", "id", String.valueOf(id));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    String response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    return new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (HttpResponseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
return null;
```

Comment: thank i updated my code.i changed Arraylist to hashmap.and when i call my function like this String result= setHttpParameters("parameters here") result is nothink

Comment: Are you still calling response = httpclient.execute(httppost)? setHttpParameters isn't supposed to give any result.

Comment: i logend response inside my function but  result is nothink

Comment: thank you .but i did not understand your code how  i can  use setHttpParameters method? how i can  call this method, i tryed but i have syntacs error

Comment: your setHttpParameters contains two parameters and how i can use  your  setHttpParameters?

Comment: I edited my answer. Copy-paste and it should work.

Comment: thanks but your code contains errors(Syntacs error)

Comment: Then please tell me exactly where.

Comment: what is a client in your code? and also i can not call setHttpParameters method. i have syntacs error

Comment: Yup, that was an error. And setHttpParameters just has to be static in your case. Check my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Create bean class for data what you want to send for example : " if you want to send Objecttype , lang_code etc . you can create class like LocaleInformation" and then create ArrayList of "LocaleInformation" type. After that it would be easy to create LocaleInformation instance and assign member variables values to it and then add it to ArrayList.

Or

You can simply use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) library for faster networking.Many examples are available out there for Volley.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Google's Volley.
http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Everything is much simpler. If you're trying to send an ArrayList, best to send it as JSON object, imo.